# How to call an URL into HTML instead of <a href="">?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, twitter, blogger

I want to put social links to author box in blogger,
There is many of authors in the blog, 
Google call the Google+ profiles by the code :

```
expr:href='data:post.authorProfileUrl'
```

Instead of `<a href="">`

The problem is I just can add one fb or twitter author profile by using `<a href="">` .
Is it an solution to give the authors social links an ID and call it into the HTML ?

The Blogger Author box code :

```
<li><a class='external external-link' href='#' rel='nofollow' target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-facebook'/></a></li>

<li><a class='external external-link' href='#' rel='nofollow' target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-twitter'/></a></li>

<li><a class='external external-link' expr:href='data:post.authorProfileUrl' rel='nofollow' title='Google+' target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-google-plus'/></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get author social links other than Google+ from Blogger but you can check by author using a conditional statement and display certain content with particular author

```
<b:if cond='data:post.author == "first author name"'>
  <!-- first author social links -->
<b:elseif cond='data:post.author == "second author name"'>
  <!-- second author social links -->
</b:if>
```

Comment: Thank you @Bassam, Its seems like logical solution but I have no idea how to edit it, I putted the CSS and HTML code here : https://jsfiddle.net/4g9ooqtu/